# Cocoa Touch - Alternative to viewDidLoad Method

Tags: cocoa-touch, viewdidload

I am creating an app that reads a text file from the web.  WHen the app first runs, I want a splash page to be presented with a logo.  I have a SplashViewController and a MainController.  I am using some code from a tutorial that allows you to add a subview to the MainController's applicationDidFinishLaunching method and replace the main controller's view with the splash screen (follow so far?  Trying my best to explain)

The issue I am having is that I want the splash screen to be present until the data is loaded from the web and animate an activity indicator.  However, I am retrieving the data from within the viewDidLoad method in the MainController and the app starts retrieving the data before the splash screen loads so there is a delay before the user sees anything.

Is there another method that I can use to begin the retrieval process after the splash has been displayed?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `-viewDidAppear:` instead of `-viewDidLoad:`? The former is sent when the view has been added to the window whilst the latter is sent when the view has been loaded (from a nib file), i.e., hasn’t been shown yet.